# Windows XP: Replace the standard "New Folder" action with a WSH script

Tags: windows, scripting, directory, wsh

**Problem:** I have a custom WSH script that creates a new directory in a similar manner to the standard "New Folder" action in the Windows desktop. This script, however, does a couple of extra things; such as allowing me to create a pre-defined set of child directories (optional); as well as allowing me to add notes and reminders if the directory is work-related or for a particular customer.

I would like to be able to make it so this script runs every time I invoke the "New Folder" action in windows xp.

**Question:** What options are available (if any) to allow me to replace the standard creation of new directories in WindowsXP so that my custom WSH script runs instead?

**Bonus Question:** Regardless of whether and how cumbersome it is to do such a thing in Windows XP, does Windows Vista make it any easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard creation of folders in Windows XP is [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855%28VS.85%29.aspx). This is a Kernel32 function.

Since you're referring to "New Folder", and expect to have UI, I think you are actually refering to Explorer, the default shell for XP. "Ne Folder"is a predefined entry in the context menu, and that list is extensible. However, you'll notice a divider line. "Folder'and "shortcut" are built-ins; the other entries are configured. It would be trivial to add a "New Folder Structure" entry below the divider (ShellNew key in HKCR)